# Not able to boot into MacBook Air (2017)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, ssd, recovery

I have a macbook Air 128 GB (2017) model. It was working fine, until I decided to reset it. I restarted and went into recovery mode, into Disk Utility and erased the “Macintosh HD” volume group. After that, the disk utility menu showed only the Apple SSD Volume, at which point I restarted the mac. It showed a folder with a question mark instead of the apple logo, which seemed fair since I had deleted the default startup volume. But, the issue was that I wasn’t able to go into the built-in recovery mode after that. Whenever I try to go into recovery mode now, It automatically goes to internet recovery which doesn’t even show a progress bar, just keeps failing and shows the error code 1003f.

I tried the following already:

1. Resetting the NVRAM
2. Using an ethernet cable during Internet Recovery.
3. Tried to change my Startup Disk. Also, it shows Internet Recovery as the only option in this mode.

I don’t know what to do now, please help.